# innerHTML method cannot add a single </div> </a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, frontend

I want to change the structure of a HTML DOM.

```
$('#tabs').html("<div></div>")
```

It works.

But I want to end last `<div>` by

```
$('#tabs').html("</div>")
```

It seems nothing happens.

Can I change DOM structure by add `</div>` `</a>` ?

I know it's funny. But I still want to know why a single closing tag won't work. Both JQuery.html and innerHTML API never reveal closing tag is void

Comment: Setting the content to a closing tag does not make any sense at all. What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: i think he is trying to add the `<div>`  dom by just a closing `</div>` instead of using both .......  in creation ........

Comment: I know it's may funny. But I want to know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @d4rkb1ue what would you expect a single closing tag to mean in terms of the DOM? If you had a stray closing tag in your HTML, the browser would just ignore it - that's exactly what's happening here.

Comment: Also note that you're not *adding* to the content of that `"#tabs"` element - the `.html()` method completely replaces the contents of that element with the content you pass it.

Comment: @Pointy I use ejs on Express.Node.js to create  module htmls. If I can add close tag, I can easily change some structure.

Comment: @ Pointy Actually, I want to achieve `$('#tabs').html('</div><div class="newStyle">')` . So I can easily change the style of some block without using DOM manipulate methods.

Comment: @d4rkb1ue again, calling `.html()` **replaces all the content**.  It does not append content.

Comment: @ Pointy I know. `#tabs` is just a label. I use it like boundary.

Comment: `$("#tabs").html("something")` replaces the **contents** of the element with the id "tabs".  It does not add HTML content before or after that element. You just can't manipulate the DOM that way.

Comment: The reason it does not work is because you are not manipulating a text file but a dom object tree. If you are doing that I would guess you are doing something wrong. show a little more of your code and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @ Pointy Thanks! I just understand. It's the contents not itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can build all of the content in an string and after put in the #tabs element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myContent = "<a href=''>something...";
    myContent += "<div>";
    myContent += " ... content here ...";
    myContent += "</div>";
    myContent += "</a>";
    $("#tabs").html(myContent);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But I still want to know why a single closing tag won't work. Both JQuery.html  and innerHTML API never reveal closing tag is void

Comment: @d4rkb1ue a closing tag without an opening tag is nonsense. That's why it doesn't work. The browser ignores it.

Comment: I believe that is because issues with "Unbalanced Tree" and sintax.